# Objects not sorted after creation Core Data SwiftUI

Tags: swift, core-data, swiftui

At the beginning on the app install, I create some objects, but they are not sorted after creation on the UI, I have to close the app and open it so they are displayed correctly. This is the code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

@FetchRequest(
    entity: ProgrammingLanguage.entity(),
    sortDescriptors: [
        NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \ProgrammingLanguage.id, ascending: true)
    ]
) var languages: FetchedResults<ProgrammingLanguage>

@Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext

var body: some View {

    NavigationView {
        VStack {
            List(languages, id: \.self) { language in
                Text(language.name ?? "Unknown")
            }
        }
    }
    .onAppear{

        for i in 1...5 {
            let language = ProgrammingLanguage(context: self.managedObjectContext)
            language.name = "\(i) SwiftUI"
            language.creator = "Some text"
            do {
                try self.managedObjectContext.save()
            } catch {
            }
        }

    }
}
}
```

How can I make it be sorted automatically after creation? Also when created for the first time that part of the screen appears blank, it seems as the UI is not aware of Core Data changes.

Comment: Needs more details about actions.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look, I updated the post @Asperi

Comment: No, the sorting is correct. I need to sort it by id so when they are created  1, 2, ... they follow that order @Asperi  can you show me a simple example where this sort of data can me created and sorted at creation?

Comment: @Asperi I updated the code to the simplest example possible replicating what's happening

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems that it is just not assigned in the provided code, because naming attribute by `id` means noting in CoreData (and by default remains 0), so at least with added below it is updated & sorted properly (in testing model id is Int32, but it is not important)

```
for i in 1...5 {
    let language = ProgrammingLanguage(context: self.managedObjectContext)
    language.id = Int32(i)           // << here !!
    language.name = "\(i) SwiftUI"
```

Tested with Xcode 11.4 / iOS 13.4